# Creating points with attributes from coordinates in ArcPy

Tags: arcpy, shapefile, point, fields-attributes

I know how to create points by coordinates with arcpy using the following code:

```
import arcpy

ptList =[[20.000,43.000],[25.500, 45.085],[26.574, 46.025], [28.131, 48.124]]
pt = arcpy.Point()
ptGeoms = []
for p in ptList:
   pt.X = p[0]
   pt.Y = p[1]
   ptGeoms.append(arcpy.PointGeometry(pt))

arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(ptGeoms, r"C:\Temp\test.shp")
```

But in my case, every coordinate pair also has an additional text attribute that needs to be written to the shapefile. What would be the approach?

Comment: Have you seen these threads [Python Script to Add Fields to Feature Classes](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/130588/python-script-to-add-fields-to-feature-classes) and [Adding Coordinates to shapefile using ArcPy](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/130588/python-script-to-add-fields-to-feature-classes)?

Comment: **Always** use the SpatialReference parameter when constructing PointGeometry from Point, or you risk losing precision during construction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest to use insert cursor, make sure that the field allready exists in the feature class (AddField if necessary)

```
ptList =[["value1",(20.000,43.000)],["value2",(25.500, 45.085)],["value3",(26.574, 46.025)], ["value4",(28.131, 48.124)]]

cursor = arcpy.da.InsertCursor('C:/temp/test.shp',
                               ['FieldName', 'SHAPE@XY'])

# Insert new rows that include the field value and a x,y coordinate

for row in ptList:
    cursor.insertRow(row)

# Delete cursor object
del cursor
```